# I am given an annual interest on my money. How do I calculate how much interest I earn daily?

Tags: interest-rate

If an institution is giving me an interest of 7% pa and the interest will be earned daily. How do I calculate how much do I earn per day?

I tried it calculate like this:

```
(7/100)/365 * PRINCIPAL = my daily interest
```

That was my assumption - however, when I received the daily interest, the  amount was lower than I calculated with using the formula above.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You are not considering compound interest. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest).:

> Compound interest is the addition of interest to the principal sum of a loan or deposit, or in other words, interest on interest.
>
> [...] 
> Compound interest is contrasted with simple interest, where previously accumulated interest is not added to the principal amount of the current period, so there is no compounding.

In your case the daily interest would be
$$
\left( \sqrt[365]{1+\frac{7}{100}} - 1\right) \cdot \text{principal}.
$$
This way the daily interest rate comes out to approximately 
0.00018538... 
Your method yielded 
0.00019178... 
so there is a small but significant difference.

Comment: nitpicking, but the daily _interest_  would be that formula, `- principal`

Comment: @njzk2 Well nitpicked!